# How do I use a `scope` to find all the records for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have:

```
scope :all_somethings, lambda { find(:all) }
```

But this returns an array (and not a `ActiveRecord::Relation`), and so I if I called `order` on it, I get an error:

```
@somethings = current_user.somethings.all_somethings.order("created_at desc")

undefined method `order' for #<Array:0xb6ebedc2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just do

```
@everything = MyModel.all
```

You should just be able to remove the "all_somethings" from your line:

```
@somethings = current_user.somethings.order("created_at desc")
```

Comment: `MyModel.all` will return an array, not a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. Besides, I want to know if it is possible to get all the records using a scope. Ps. I do know about the techniques you mention.

Comment: Do you have a `default_scope` that limits the records being returned? If not there's no need to have a scope to get all records as accessing the relation will always return all records applicable. Did you try the second bit of code I gave?

Comment: If you want the ActiveRecord Relation object, just do `MyModel.scoped` instead.

Comment: Note that (starting in ActiveRecord 4) `all` returns a relation.